# Mongoid upsert with a different key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, upsert, database

Is it possible to upsert into a mongodb collection with a JSON/hash of fields, but instead of using the `_id` ObjectId field, to use a different indexed field such as `external_id`?

I am using it to update some items that I receive from a feed on a daily basis, and as such, the feed items don't contain my internal ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to upsert with a custom id in Mongoid, but only in 3.0.0.rc circa June 27, 2012.

app/models/item.rb

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :external_id, type: String
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ external_id }
  field :text, type: String
end
```

test/unit/item_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Item.delete_all
  end

  test "external id" do
    Item.new( text: 'Lorem ipsum' ).upsert
    Item.new( external_id: 'an external id', text: 'dolor sit amet' ).upsert
    puts Item.all.to_a.collect{|item|item.inspect}
  end
end
```

output

Run options: --name=test_external_id

```
# Running tests:

#<Item _id: 4ff202501f98ce8202c03268, _type: nil, external_id: nil, text: "Lorem ipsum">
#<Item _id: an external id, _type: nil, external_id: "an external id", text: "dolor sit amet">
.

Finished tests in 0.028232s, 35.4208 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

To do this you will have to install from github, visit and clone from

```
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid

bundle install
bundle exec rake install
```

Here's the link to the commit that makes this possible.

```
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/commit/3062363bad3ab947d7689502d6805652b20e89a0
```